# Automatically mark messages sent to myself as read

Tags: thunderbird

I like to BCC myself in all my replies so that it shows the entire chain of messages in my Inbox (Account Properties -> Copies and Folders -> "Bcc these email addresses").

But I dont like to receive them as new unread messages that ping me on arrival. Is there a way I can mark those messages automatically as read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a "Filter" (see the tools menu).

Set filter criteria to check for <strike>both the sender and the Bcc headers</strike> the sender containing your address and the action to mark as read. You could also then add a second action to file it in a folder.

However, there is also a different way to achieve this. Under "Copies & Folders" in the Account Settings, you can save a copy of sent mail in any folder you like including the inbox - indeed, this is what I do. These saved copies are automatically stored as "read".

Comment: You can't filter on Bcc on incoming messages. Bcc by it's nature doesn't include a "Bcc" line in the message header; that would defeat the point of Bcc.

Seems to me that filtering on sender (being yourself) should be sufficient.

Comment: Oops, good spot! Yes, you are right. My second option is still best though as long as you don't want to do something else at the same time.

Comment: Your second option works, but also this: under "copies and folders", there is an option "Place replies in the folder of the message being replied to". just fyi.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't bother to mention that but I do use it. I much prefer to have everything together.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a rule using the From field and mark the same as read. I have tried and it is working
Please try.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.